# OnPressed FloatingActionButton set Icon

Tags: dart, flutter

```
    class Tickets extends StatefulWidget {

      int groupid;
      int event_id;

      Tickets([this.groupid, this.event_id]);

      @override
      _TicketsState createState() => new _TicketsState();
    }
     List<Widget> ListMyWidgets(ticketGroups) {

    IconData icon = Icons.undo;
    List<Widget> list = new List();
    list.add(new CupertinoNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      leading:
          new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Text(ticketGroups[0]['ticket_name'],
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: Colors.white)),
      ),

      trailing: new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Text('${ticketGroups.length}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: Colors.white))),


    ));


      for (int i = 0; i < ticketGroups.length; i++) {

        list.add(

          new GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragStart: (event) {
                print("checked in");
                print(ticketGroups[i]['id']);
                setState(() {
                  _getStatusIn(ticketGroups[i]);
                });
              },
              onDoubleTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _getStatusOut(ticketGroups[i]);
                });
              },
              child: new Card(
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: new Text(
                          "${ticketGroups[i]['ticket_name']}",
                          style:
                          const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins')),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: new Text(ticketGroups[i]["used"].toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins')),
                    ),


                    new SizedBox(
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 30.0,
                        child: new IconButton(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),

                          icon: new FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  icon = Icons.check_circle;
                                });

                              },
                              child: new Icon(icon, size: 20.0),heroTag: null)
                       child: new Icon(icon,size: 25.0),heroTag: null)
                          )

                        )
]
                    ),


              )),
        );
      }

  }
```

This is the updated part of the previous post, as you can see I have done what I have been advised for, however when I hit the Floating Action Button, the icon does not change within it.
This is the updated part of the previous post, as you can see I have done what I have been advised for, however when I hit the Floating Action Button, the icon does not change within it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Declare icon to be displayed Globally

```
IconData icon = Icons.check_circle;
```

2) Use this icon instead of hardcoded icon

```
new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: (){
       setState(() {
           icon = icon == Icons.undo ? Icons.check_circle : Icons.undo; // Change icon and setState to rebuild
       });
    },
    child: new Icon(icon, size: 25.0),heroTag: null)
);
```

Comment: @HeyabRedda This will definitely work. You need to make sure that you are operating in a `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Yes. As @creativecreatorormaybenot said in order to change the state of a widget you must use Stateful widget.

Comment: It is setting the initial icon as check_circle, whoever when I hit the button, it does not change, and yes, I am working within the StatefulWidget

Comment: Post your full modified code. Then only we can identify the issue.

Comment: 'icon' in you code is not a global variable. It's declared inside a method. Hence every time you call this method, 'the value of icon will be set to Icons.undo'. To make icon global declare it outside of the method 'ListMyWidgets'.

Comment: Thank you it works now, however what I was actually looking for is slightly different since I am looking to keep changing from circle to undo anytime that the user hit the button, and according to it, I want to trigger a function.
According to your advise once the Icon has been set to be undo, I cannot change it back anymore.

Comment: Instead of this                                                                                      
       setState(() {
           icon = Icons.undo; 
       });                                                                                                                                                                 Use this,                                                                                                              
        setState(() {  
            icon = icon == Icons.undo ? Icons.check_circle : Icons.undo; 
        });